# Can fetchmail write to file?

Tags: fetchmail

During testing of a new server I need to test the fetchmail functionality but I can't get it to work the way I expect it to. How can I send the fetched email either to a specified file or to stdout?

My `/etc/fetchmailrc` looks something like this:

```
set syslog

set daemon 10

# TEST
poll mail.example.com proto imap
  user "ulf" password "testpassword" idle
  ssl
  folder "INBOX/test_2016-10-24"
  keep
  mda "tee /tmp/fetch_test"
```

I then run fetchmail like:

```
$ sudo fetchmail -vk -f /etc/fetchmailrc
```

or (as suggested [here](http://www.fetchmail.info/fetchmail-FAQ.html#R2)):

```
$ sudo fetchmail -vk -m cat -f /etc/fetchmailrc
```

I have also tried [this](https://gist.github.com/cristianp6/c063e36826a6b1623f3d) (Write retrieved emails in a file) without success.

There is one mail in the specified folder and when I run any of the commands above a lot of data is produced in `/var/log/syslog` before it halts. The last 3 lines indicates that there is one message found but then?

```
...
Oct 25 15:16:25 example fetchmail[7271]: 1 message (1 seen) for ulf at mail.example.com (folder INBOX/test_2016-10-24).
Oct 25 15:16:25 example fetchmail[7271]: IMAP> A0005 IDLE
Oct 25 15:16:25 example fetchmail[7271]: IMAP< + idling
```

Answer (score 2):

Seems my error is obvious if you think about it or read the output:

```
...
Oct 25 15:16:25 example fetchmail[7271]: 1 message (1 seen) ...
...
```

**1 seen** is the key here. Only mails marked as *unread* in the mailbox will be fetched. Mails that has already been *read* or seen will not be fetched.